# TextBox muda o valor para decimal (EN) ao pressionar o TAB, porem eu quero deixar moeda (REAL) o campo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Tenho um campo

```
 <TextBox x:Name="TbTotalICMS" Style="{StaticResource MeuTextBoxValor}" Text="{Binding Vicms}" />
```

Meu Vicms e um decimal. Ao pressionar a tecla TAB, o valor que esta 1,00 (exemplo) ele vira 100. Pois como ele e um decimal no inglês ele tira a virgula e troca por ponto. 
Eu preciso que ao pressionar o TAB ele continua como esta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi isso colocando um ConverterCulture!

```
 <TextBox x:Name="TbTotalICMS" Style="{StaticResource MeuTextBoxValor}" Text="{Binding Vicms,  ConverterCulture='pt-BR'}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No evento de `LostFocus` existe sempre a possibilidade de converter/forçar o valor para o formato que pretendemos:

```
NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();

// número de casas decimais
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
// separador de casas decimais
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
// separador de milhares
numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
string value = DoubleValue.ToString("N", numberFormatInfo);
```